# 1 writer server 1 search server work on realtime

Tags: java, solr

I have 2 server with one of the writing process in the meantime would like to have one of the search process with the search process has to be at the same time can help with information on this subject?

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit difficult to understand the question.  But if I understand this, you want to index to a solr server and search from different instance of a solr server.

If this is the case, please look at [SolrReplication](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication).

Comment: yes you're right one for the server to search for one of the indexing, but Solr search server, a server and indexing data which is common during the indexing process, but the search server that searches tomcat server is restarted to see the new insertions sees the newly added documents